# How to sort SQL Server Report Builder Matrix Descending?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I have a report with the following columns:

- Machine
- Shift
- Reason
- MinutesDown

My sql statement for the datasource sorts by shift descending.  In the Query Designer I get results sorted as I would expect.  When I insert a matrix (see images below) the shifts are not sorted descending.  How do I manipulate my report to put the shifts in the order that I would like them to appear ?

[image: Matrix Wizard]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created the matrix, bring up the *Shift* row group properties, something like:

[image]

In the Group Properties, set the sorting as **Z to A**:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks.  Any suggestions how I might be able to sort shift 3 then 1 then 2 ?

Comment: Sure, you can add an extra sorting expression before the one you have now, something like `iif(Fields!Shift.Value = 3, 0, 1)` i.e. sort *Shift=3* before all other values. If you need more information, probably best to raise a new question.